# IPV6 Binding Failure Error: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: ethernet, c, ipv6, bind, sockets

I have configured Ubuntu Linux system with the following interfaces & assigned IPV6 addresses as follows:

```
    **Eth0:** Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:56:8d:57:64
    inet addr:192.168.254.10 Bcast:0.0.0.0 Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:5764/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
    RX packets:74231424 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:400372550 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:24514286488 (24.5 GB) TX bytes:115992171490 (115.9 GB)

    **Eth1:** Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:56:8d:7c:4c
    inet addr:192.168.1.10 Bcast:0.0.0.0 Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:7c4c/64 Scope:Link
    inet6 addr: fc00:1234:1::10/120 Scope:Global
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
    RX packets:434933479 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:39666183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:126065364448 (126.0 GB) TX bytes:14437801257 (14.4 GB)

**Eth2:** Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:56:8d:56:14
inet addr:192.168.2.10 Bcast:0.0.0.0 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fc00:1234:2::10/120 Scope:Global
inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:5614/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:480068741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:34145702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:146795537550 (146.7 GB) TX bytes:10045338657 (10.0 GB)
```

**2.** I wanted to do Socket programming using IPV6 sockets. The code snippet that I have written is as follows:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 sin
Ipv6_fdr = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)

bzero(&sin, sizeof(sin));  
sin.sin6_family = AF_INET6;  
sin.sin6_port = htons(2152);  
if ((setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(int))) < 0)  
memcpy(&(sin.sin6_addr), "fc00:1234:1::10",sizeof(sin.sin6_addr));  
if ((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin)))< 0)
```

**3.** After successful compilation, I’m getting IPV6 bind failure Error with the following error number & name:

```
EADDRNOTAVAIL 99 /* Cannot assign requested address.
```

After certain number of attempts for IPV6 Binding it throws Segmentation Fault error.

It would be great if someone could help me on what mistake I’m doing here & why IPV6 binding is failing?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799216/i-got-error-in-run-time-that-cannot-assign-requested-address-in-c-under-linux

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
memcpy(&(sin.sin6_addr), "fc00:1234:1::10",sizeof(sin.sin6_addr));
```

is wrong; that's absolutely not how you set the address and port of a socket. Please see `man 7 ipv6` and the question "[How to set sockaddr_in6::sin6_addr byte order to network byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027989/how-to-set-sockaddr-in6sin6-addr-byte-order-to-network-byte-order)" on StackOverflow. For your use case you probably want to use `inet_pton` to convert the address from text to binary form.